# conversion from string to type 'date' is not valid With right date string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm facing a strange error

I'm using the following line to parse string to date

```
DepartureDate = CDate("20" & year & "/" & month & "/" & day & " " & hour & ":" & minute)
```

And it work fine.

But sometimes I got the following error from my site page

> Conversion from string "2013/04/14 18:15" to type 'Date' is not valid.

The string is right date,so why got this error.

The error stop when I restart the IIS

What happened to the IIS so it throw-ed this error???

and what shall I do to handle this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably because the culture settings change.

Instead of putting the components together in a string and then parse it, create a value directly from the components:

```
DepartureDate = New DateTime(2000 + year, month, day, hour, minute, 0)
```

Comment: The occurre many times and stop when I restart the IIS and after a while it start again